How to keep my components state after it unrenders and rerenders?
I have two screens that are conditionally rendered. I would like the state of the screens to remain the same after navigating away from the screen and returning.
For example, in the reproducible code below, when I am on ScreenA and scroll the map, click to ScreenB, and then return to ScreenA, I would like the map to still be where I originally scrolled. However it renders like new again, erasing the users progress from before.
How can I keep ScreenA at the same place the user was, after navigating to and from ScreenB? I need to keep the buttons visible throughout changing screens.
I tried using useCallback as you can see but no luck. The link below takes you to snack.expo.io which contains all the code and a simulator ready to go.
EDIT:: To be clear, I do not want to use a state management system to store where the user left off on the map so I can later initially render there. This is because there are many components on these screens on top of the map in this example. I only included the map because that was all that was needed for a reproducible example. I do not think it is ideal to manually store and attempt to initially render where the user left off for every component.
Reproducible code on snack expo io.
Code here as well
export default function App() {
  const [screen, setScreen] = useState('A');

  function navToA() {
    setScreen('A');
  }

  function navToB() {
    setScreen('B');
  }

  const RenderScreen = useCallback((props) => {
    return <ScreenA />;
  }, []);

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      {screen === 'A' && <RenderScreen />} // users progress is lost when moving to screenB and back
      {screen === 'B' && <ScreenB />}

      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navToA()} style={styles.buttonStyleA}>
        <Text>A</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>

      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navToB()} style={styles.buttonStyleB}>
        <Text>B</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}


Rather use redux. The values which you have passed to Map as initial value can be stored in redux, and whereever the user navigates before going to next screen can be stored in redux, so whenever you come back to screen A, it will show the value stored in redux(which is the last navigates position by the user). Don't use state hook for this.

Its not just the state of the variable I want to store. Its the state of the entire screen. In my description, the example I give is scrolling far far away on the map. When returning to that screen, I want to still be there. You could argue to store where the user left off and to navigate there upon render, however that solves this one specific example. I want the solution to save the condition of every process of the screen like stack navigation does.

To add to my comment above, If theres a scrollview, I want the scrollview position to the same. If theres a list, I want the list to be at the same spot. It isnt a feasible solution to manually track all these things

Well, for scrollview to the last position where the user was can be achieved by scrollTo. On the first render your scrollTo can point to default, which is start of the scrollView and that value can be stored in redux, and when the user scrolls and then navigate to other screen then the last position where the user left the scroll can be stored in redux on onPress method of navigating to different screen, by this, when you return to this screen again, your screen will scrollTo the position where you left off.

Sorry, I think you misunderstood. I also mentioned that is not something I want to do, as that is very example specific. I would like the condition of the screen to be the same across all aspects of the screen. It is not ideal to track every component on my screen manually like this. I previously mentioned "You could argue to store where the user left off and to navigate there upon render, however that solves this one specific example. I want the solution to save the condition of every process of the screen like stack navigation does."

The reason for that^ is because the reproducible code I am providing does not contain the countless other components on those screens. The example is as plain as possible

You have to store the state at a higher level - outside the component. For components whose code you do not fully control, such as in React Navigation, this may not be feasible.
If you cannot lift the relevant state out of the screen you're unmounting, then I fear there is no workaround for you except to keep the screen mounted.
In that case, your best bet is likely to display one screen or the other visually, but not actually unmount it.

Thats an unfortunate solution, I appreciate the insight though

Indeed. Unfortunately I believe you have no alternatives here.

Performance doesnt even seem to drop much at all keeping them both mounted despite all the components the screens hold. Glad to see it. So far its the solution im going with.

Glad to hear it! One thing to look out for is added RAM usage. One screen won't break the camel's back but if you use that pattern a lot you may accumulate a bit of RAM and it's not always obvious on mobile until you start running the system out of RAM.

Good to know. Performance is something im just starting to measure as I have finalized my app. Definitely will be the only place I use this kind of implementation and will check the RAM before and after in different scenarios! Thank you again!
